# How to fix http://localhost:8080 is not working

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, localhost

http://localhost:8080 is not working in eclipse.
I am using App Engine Standard at localhost (2) server for the project but when I start it, localhost:8080 doesn't work.

Even when I run the java project it shows Conflicts with running server "App Engine Standard at localhost (2)"
server port: 8080. I have cleaned and restarted multiple times.

Comment: check if you don't have some other process listening to port 8080. Maybe even another instance of the dev server, still hanging around.

Comment: @DanCornilescu you are right. I just restart my IDE. It starts working.